# laravel ajax request 404

Tags: jquery, laravel, datatable

I am using laravel 5.0 ON ajax request it says
JOB CONTROLLER

class JobController extends Controller {

```
public function __construct() {
    //$this->middleware('auth');
}

// function will process the ajax request
public function getJobs(Request $request) {

    $draw = $request->get('draw');
    $start = $request->get('start');
    $length = $request->get('length');


    $data = array(
        'draw' => $draw,
        'recordsTotal' => $total_members,
        'recordsFiltered' => $total_members,
        'data' => $jobsObj,
    );


    echo json_encode($data);
 }
```

I am using DataTable as well . 
Routes.php contain the code

```
   Route::get('JobController/getJobs', 'JobController@getJobs');
   Route::post('JobController/getJobs', 'JobController@getJobs');
```

Ajax request code in view

```
   $( document ).ready(function() {

   $('#all-member-table').DataTable( {
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50,100,-1],[10, 25, 50,100,"All"]],
    "ajax": {
            url: "JobController/getJobs"                
        },columns": [
        { data: "job_no" },
        { data: "br" },
        { data: "Customer" },
        { data: "Manifest" },
        { data: "HBL" },
        { data: "created_at" },
        { data: "Status" }

    ]
       } );
       });
```

Error :
Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.
First time it load perfectly but second time it do not load and throw
error 404

```
1/1 NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 145:
in RouteCollection.php line 145
at RouteCollection->match(object(Request)) in Router.php line 729
at Router->findRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 652
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 628
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 214
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 141
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in 
 VerifyCsrfToken.php line 43
 at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in 
  VerifyCsrfToken.php line 17
                    at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), 
             object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
                  at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) 
      in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 55
 at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in 
            Pipeline.php line 125
     at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in 
    StartSession.php line 61
         at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in 
       Pipeline.php line 125
   at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in 
                   AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 36
            at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), 
            object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
     at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in 
     EncryptCookies.php line 40
 at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php 
     line 125
   at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in 
            CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 42
                  at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in 
          Pipeline.php line 125
               at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 101
      at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 115
         at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 84
       at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 53
         at require_once('C:\wamp\www\gls\public\index.php') in server.php line 22
```

Comment: What does your jobcontroller loom like?

Comment: When you hit the this route what is the full url you have in your browser? Make sure it is www.site.com/jobController/getJobs . It sounds like you may be nesting your url routes like www.site.com/jobController/getJobs/jobController/getJobs. Therefore it doesn&#39;t exists.

Comment: Ajax call page url http://localhost:8000/job

Comment: Now using Route::get('job/getJobs', 'JobController@getJobs'); still not working fine .

Comment: Well you what you have shown from your routes file, 'job' is not a valid route.

Comment: On first ajax call it work fine but with second ajax call it says 404 ...

Comment: JobController/getJobs is but not job.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147038/discussion-between-peter-and-alex-mac).